# Extract page from PDF using iText and clojure

Tags: clojure, itext

I am trying to extract a single page from a pdf with clojure by translating the splitPDF method I found here http://viralpatel.net/blogs/itext-tutorial-merge-split-pdf-files-using-itext-jar/

I keep getting this error

**IOException Stream Closed  java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes (:-2)**

This prevents me from opening the document while the repl is still open. Once I close the repl I'm able to access the document.

Why do I get the error?

How do I fix it ?

How can I make it more clojurey?

```
(import '(com.itextpdf.text Document)
            '(com.itextpdf.text.pdf PdfReader PdfWriter PdfContentByte PdfImportedPage BaseFont)
            '(java.io File FileInputStream FileOutputStream InputStream OutputStream))

(defn extract-page [src dest pagenum]
  (with-open  [ d (Document.) 
                os (FileOutputStream. dest)]
    (let [ srcpdf (->> src FileInputStream. PdfReader.)
           destpdf  (PdfWriter/getInstance d os)]
         (doto d
            (.open )
            (.newPage ))
          (.addTemplate 
                (.getDirectContent destpdf)
                (.getImportedPage destpdf srcpdf pagenum) 0 0))))
```

Comment: does it start working again when you re-open the REPL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to close the document:

```
(close. d)
```

The following code works:

```
(import '(com.itextpdf.text Document)
            '(com.itextpdf.text.pdf PdfReader PdfWriter PdfContentByte PdfImportedPage BaseFont)
            '(java.io File FileInputStream FileOutputStream InputStream OutputStream))

(defn extract-page [src dest pagenum]
  (with-open  [ is (FileInputStream. src)
                os (FileOutputStream. dest)]
    (let [ srcpdf (PdfReader. src)
           d (Document.)
           destpdf  (PdfWriter/getInstance d os)]
         (doto d
            (.open )
            (.newPage ))
         (println "Number of pages" (.getNumberOfPages srcpdf))
         (.addTemplate 
                (.getDirectContent destpdf)
                (.getImportedPage destpdf srcpdf pagenum) 0 0)
         (.close d))))
```

EDIT:

In case you are interested, I found that using apache pdfbox is easier.

```
(import '(org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel PDDocument)
        '(org.apache.pdfbox.util PDFTextStripper)
        '(java.io File OutputStreamWriter FileOutputStream BufferedWriter))

(defn convert-to-text [src dest]
  (with-open [ pd (PDDocument/load (File. src))
               wr (BufferedWriter. (OutputStreamWriter. (FileOutputStream. (File. dest))))]
    (let [ stripper (PDFTextStripper.)]
      (println "Number of pages" (.getNumberOfPages pd))
      (.writeText stripper pd wr))))
```

Comment: Why did you take document out of the with-open and move input stream in?

Comment: I am also learning Clojure. I was just not comfortable with opening document in the with-open body (instead of in the binding) and relying on the automatic close. You are right about your original code not needing to close it explicitly though. I think the error in your original code is you forgot to close the FileInputStream. But, then I don't know why you got the error in FileOutputStream.